# Avoiding while (!is_eof)

Tags: c++, stream, scope, while-loop, state-machine

I'm working with a (C++) library, where the object needs to be initialized with a stream. The sample code provided with the library uses this code:

```
// Declare the input stream
HfstInputStream *in = NULL;

try 
{
    // This sets up the special stream object for the later object (see below)
    in = new HfstInputStream("pathToFile.hfsto");
} 
// catch errors...
// {omitted}

// Initialize the object
while (not in->is_eof()) {
    if (in->is_bad()) 
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Stream cannot be read." << std::endl;
        exit(1); 
    }
    // Here we initialize the object using the stream
    HfstTransducer t(*in);
}
```

My problem is that this object cannot be used outside of the while loop because of scoping. and I have to declare it with the stream (as far as I can tell), so I can't declare and then  initialize it with the stream inside the loop.

My questions are (1) am I wrong? Can I actually declare it outside the loop somehow? (2) is there another (better) way to do this that avoids the loop altogether. For example, if I were to use try/catch and catch the exceptions.

I'm very new to C++ and looking to find out best practices, so please let me know what's what. Thanks.

Also, to be clear, I'm looking to make a class that would use a persistant version of this object so I don't have to constantly create/destroy these objects every time I need to use them.

PS: [here's a link to the documentation for the object if it is relevant](http://hfst.sourceforge.net/hfst3/classhfst_1_1HfstTransducer.html#a80b941c9d120fbec4596002c6a979096)

EDIT: If I try to declare the variable outside the loop and then initialize it I get an error

```
HfstTransducer t;
while (not in->is_eof()) {
    t(*in);
}
// ERROR: main.cpp:47:0 main.cpp:47: error: no match for call to '(hfst::HfstTransducer) (hfst::HfstInputStream&)'
```

Am I trying to initialize it incorrectly?

Comment: `HfstTransducer t(*in);` is in the loop scope. But `HfstInputStream *in` is not, you can access it outside the loop and use to initialize another `HfstTransducer` object or just use `HfstInputStream` pointer ... Unless, of course, `HfstTransducer` constructor has move semantics and erases `HfstInputStream *in`.

Comment: Is your problem that you can't access t (which is an object of type HfstTranducer) outside of the loop?
If so then you can just declare it outside of the loop on the heap and use the new operator to initialize it inside the loop. 
If not then I just misunderstood your problem :P

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant was that I would like to keep the HfstTransducer object around outside the loop and forget about the stream after the HfstTransducer been initialized instead of building a new HfstTransducer object every time. If that is even possible, it is my goal.

Comment: Lefteris, you understood correctly. I tried what you suggested and got an error, please see my edit. Thank you for the help.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that I was just trying to initialize it incorrectly. When I do `while { t = HfstTransducer(*in); }` it works perfectly. Lefteris, thanks for giving me the hint I needed.

Comment: Okay now I understand your problem correctly I think. Refer to my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve what you need, you have to have a pointer to the object declared outside of the while scope like that:

```
//Declare the pointer to the object outside the while score. This way it will be available to you even outside of the while
HfstTransducer* t = 0;
// Initialize the object
while (not in->is_eof()) {
    if (in->is_bad()) 
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Stream cannot be read." << std::endl;
        exit(1); 
    }
    // Here we initialize the object using the stream only if it's not already been initialized before
    // thanks to Necrolis for the observation
    if(t == 0)
        t = new HfstTransducer(*in);
}
```

This will declare and initialize an object of HfstTransducer type into the heap. This means that the destructor will not be called on its own after you leave scope but that you have to explicitly call it by calling:

```
delete t;
```

EDIT: To answer to your general question about pointer vs normal object:

This is a very important part of C/C++. 
An article to better explain this can be seen [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/).

If I were to explain it in a few words by doing:

```
HfstTransducer t;
```

You are declaring an object of that type and putting it in the stack. Its life-time lasts ONLY until the end of the scope. You are not able to access it out of scope, since its destructor will be called as soon as the scope ends.

On the other hand

```
HfstTransducer*t = new HfstTransducer();
```

initializes t as an object of HfstTransducer type and places it in the heap. For what the heap is refer to the article above, but it basically is the memory allocated to your program by the operating system. In C++ you ask for memory in the heap with the operators *new* and free it with the *delete* operator. In C you achieve the same with the *free()* and *malloc()* functions.

So something in the heap is alive for the whole duration of your program unless you explicitly call its destructor. As you can do in the example by invoking *delete t;*

Failure to do so leads to what all C/C++ programmers have to face, the so called memory leaks. Which is basically memory you thought is free but is not because you forgot to delete/free it.

Comment: I found that out myself mere seconds ago, but your answer also added details I needed (like calling delete). Thank you so much for the helpful and thorough answer!

Comment: Also, what is the difference between declaring a pointer in the 2nd line versus a regular object?

Comment: you need to check that `t` hasn't already been created each loop iteration (which implies `t` must be initialized to `NULL`), else you'll leak memory.

Comment: So I should have a check like `if (t == NULL) { t = new HfstTransducer(*in) }` ?

Comment: Dougalg I changed my reply to include a few info about the heap and the stack so that you may understand what they are. 

@Necrolis. Correct observation!! Will edit again to implement that